Display the number of WooCommerce items per user in User list custom column
I work on a WordPress website with WooCommerce plugin.
My question:
How to add a new column in User table displaying the number of items.  Each customer has items in his/her inventory.  I want to count and display the number in the User table in Wordpress.
Here an example on how to display a new column, 'Billing country', in Wordpress User table:
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'rrr_add_new_user_column' );
function rrr_add_new_user_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['billing_country'] = 'Billing Country';
    return $columns;
}
 
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'rrr_add_new_user_column_content', 10, 3 );
function rrr_add_new_user_column_content( $content, $column, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'billing_country' === $column ) {
        $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
        $content = $customer->get_billing_country();
    }
    return $content;
}

I tried to replace the variable 'billing_country' with 'items' or 'inventory' but it does not work.

What does "billing country" have to do with "number of items"?  Like, why are you showing us that code?  And what problem did you encounter with trying to add a column for "number of items"?

Note that WooCommerce only allows getting, for a customer, the total number of orders ($customer->get_order_count()) and/or the total amount of purchases ($customer->get_total_spent()), but NOT the total number of items purchased.

This will be a heavy loop to check all orders by the user. Counting items for each order and sum it. What you should do is create a new user meta when the order is completed to update that value and then in the user table just show that meta value. Add an update on this meta on refund too if you want to be 100% precise.
